# How can I switch maps in Baldur's Gate 3 to know which waypoint to choose?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Baldur's Gate 3 offers a fast-traveling system via waypoints. When you open the map you can either...

- click on a waypoint on the map, or
- click on a waypoint in the waypoint list on the right.

The former is limited to the current overview map, while the latter forces you to remember the waypoint names.

**Can I somehow switch between different overview maps?**

Currently my strategy is to pick some random waypoint which I am pretty sure is on the right map (not always true :P), travel there, then open the map again and choose the actual waypoint I want to go to from the new map. That seems... a bit crude for a game of the caliber of Baldur's Gate 3.

Comment: There was supposed to be some overview map of the whole land but this seemed to have gone poof after end of Early Access. The current system is not great - especially if you sit in your camp and want to fast travel somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't. So if you don't remember which WP to go to it's really your only option to just use any random WP and then use the WP you need. So at least remember the initial WPs of every location.